# Select single row from database using mysql connector .NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've just heard about the mysql connector and I want now to take a single row from my database(every row is unique). I don't want to use a loop because it would be useless(only for one row?..). I know how to connect to a database but I just can't figure out how to select a single row. This is my code :

```
       ''Register user in dtb
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `ip`, `status`) VALUES ('" & My.User.Name.Split("\")(1) & "','" & ip_temp & "','1')", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        ''Get user's Id from dtb  -->this is where I'm having troubles
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT 'id' FROM `users` WHERE name='" & My.User.Name.Split("\")(1) & "' ", conn)
        dtb_data = cmd.ExecuteScalar

        Debug.Print(dtb_data(0))
```

It doesn't work. 
      The error is: "**Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader'.**" (of course...). I know that it must look something like "dtb_data['id']" (from php) but this command doesn't exist in VB.Net. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns single value from single row. Therefore in your case `dtb_data` must be declared as `String`. Most probably this is mistake and it should be declared as `Int` or `Long` as you probably want to return `id`, not `'id'` as literal.

So the full example should be:

```
    Dim dtb_data as Long

    cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE name='" & My.User.Name.Split("\")(1) & "' ", conn)
    dtb_data = cmd.ExecuteScalar

    Debug.Print(dtb_data)
```